# Playing guitar with effects through mac along with song

Tags: guitar

I want to dial up a song on youtube and play along with it using my amp (and effects)through my mac laptop. I can then listen to the combo of my playing with the song (for example-Flying High Again). What cables or hardware do I need for this to work? I want to play all this through my headphones so I don't drive my wife crazy while I play. Help please?

Comment: Ever since buying Rocksmith a few years ago, I've always just used the [Aux-USB cable that came with that game](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ubisoft-10016010-Rocksmith-Real-Cable/dp/B007KGISK6) when recording guitar parts on my Mac. There's no point in buying an expensive audio interface or cable setup when something for £20-25 will do just fine, especially when you're just playing around and not recording professionally.

Answer (score 3):

Playing both your guitar AND a song on Youtube together won't be a problem as soon as you have a possibility to connect your guitar to your mac. If you've never done this before: The usual way to accomplish this is using an audio interface like [THIS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01E6T56EA). A cheaper solution is something like [THAT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EK1OTZC).
The interface is connected to your mac via USB. Of course you'll also need an audio cable to connect your amp with the interface.
Hope this helps – have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly - easiest way is to buy a USB interface for guitar. Just Google "guitar usb interface" and download Amplitube. You can run direct out into Amplitube and then use the software for the power amp/cabinet - or use the software for everything. Listen in headphones, computer speaker, monitors - whatever you have. I own a Line 6 UX1 for demo recording/practicing, and most of the time I only run my pedal board into the interface and use the software for my amplifier/cabinet/rack. A usb interface is the most important piece of gear I own for practicing, demo-ing, and just playing for fun at home.